# How to use SVG* Objects in webkit?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, webkit

I'm trying to use SVG from JavaScript (Google Chrome v21.0).  I understand how to create elements etc using XML namespace based functions.  But ... I notice that there are a whole bunch Object SVG*, e.g. SVGDocument.  But I can't find any reference to how you could use them.  For example:

```
doc1 = new SVGDocument()
```

returns:

```
TypeError: Illegal constructor
```

whilst any other constructor with insufficient arguments returns:

```
TypeError: Not enough arguments
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would create an SVG document with [document.implementation.createDocument](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Level-2-Core-DOM-createDocument)

So for SVG it would be

```
var dom = document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg:svg', null);
```

or alternatively

```
var dt = document.implementation.createDocumentType('svg:svg', '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN', 'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd');
var dom = document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg:svg', dt);
```

If you wanted/needed to set the document type too.

Comment: Experimented with the first variant.  Works Ok.  But ... can't see any advantage compared to using createElementNS, etc.

Comment: This is to create a document, not create elements. That's what you seemed to be trying to do in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Robert.  Once I create the document I would like to populate it with elements - otherwise what's the point? I continue to be perplexed by what the "purpose" of SVG* objects is if you can't use them as constructors, etc. I.e. as "normal" objects.

Comment: You can call createElementNS to create elements and document.appendChild to add the root node to the document. Once you've a root node you add the other elements as its children.